# CoffeeScript and Harmony

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a transcompile to learn and I'm completely confused.

I was reading about CoffeeScript and find it a good stuff to learn but I don't fully understand. Does it support ES6? I tried to find the answer but all I found was comparison CoffeeScript and ES6.

Then I went to the wikipedia to learn about it.
As wikipedia says:

> CoffeeScript is a programming language that transcompiles to JavaScript. It adds syntactic sugar inspired by Ruby, Python and Haskell[1] in an effort to enhance JavaScript's brevity and readability

and ES is:

> ECMAScript is the scripting language standardized by Ecma International in the ECMA-262 specification and ISO/IEC 16262. The language is widely used for client-side scripting on the Web, in the form of several well-known implementations such as JavaScript, JScript and ActionScript.

Both of them are programming language but as well as I understand ES's implemented by JS and CoffeeScript is what 'converts' to JS.

So I've got some unanswered questions:

1. Can I use all new ECMAScript features while writing CoffeeScript?
2. We do they compare ES6 and CoffeeScript?

Comment: JavaScript and CoffeeScript are different languages. The fact that it compiles to JS doesn't mean it inherits new JS features and semantics. Coffee is quite similar to JS, but other languages can be very different.

Comment: @elclanrs I didn't mention that JS and CS are the same.

Comment: So 1) You can use APIs, not syntax. 2) Because they are different languages. Not sure what else is there to expand on this.

Comment: @elclanrs Ok. For clearer description of my question and for adding some specific: Can I or will I be able to use features like generators or promises in CoffeeScript(but using it's own syntax)

Answer (score 2):

There are two bits of information that are distinct and you might be conflating:

- whether CoffeeScript generates ES6 when transpiling

  e.g. whether CS `[a, b] = [b, a]` will compile to ES6 `[a, b] = [b, a]` or to ES5 `ref = [b, a], a = ref[0], b = ref[1];`
- whether features of ES6 can be used in CoffeeScript.

  e.g. whether you can use `set = new Set()` in CS; and whether you can use ES6 generators.

The first part is "no" for now - CoffeeScript does not generate ES6 code. The second part is "yes" for innovations in the class inventory, but "no" on some of the syntactic extensions <strike>like generators</strike>.

*) Unless you use a fork such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-script-es6

Comment: CoffeeScript supports generators. These features are not simply inherited though, the syntax has to be implemented in CoffeeScript as well.

Comment: @elclanrs: "supports generators" is meaningless if it can not generate the ES6-compliant code by any available syntax. So no, the main CoffeeScript implementation does not support generators.

Comment: It does, not sure what you mean... http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20yield%201

Comment: @Amadan does not support. But is there an opportunity that it will?

Comment: @elclanrs: My apologies, it seems that I missed that development.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of discussion, ECMAScript and Javascript are identical. ECMAScript is the "formal" name of Javascript. ES6 is the latest version of it. No browser to date actually implements ES6 entirely. You cannot use ES6 features directly in browsers at the time of writing.

What people do at the moment is to write ES6, and then run it through a compiler like [Babel](http://babeljs.io) to compile it down to ES5 or other previous versions of Javascript which is actually supported in browsers today.

CoffeeScript does the same thing: it's a language which is not Javascript and is not supported by browsers directly, but it can be compiled to "simple" Javascript to run in browsers.

Why do either of these things instead of writing raw Javascript? Because both ES6 and CoffeeScript offer a simpler syntax for things which would be very verbose in plain ES5. It just makes it faster to write code, and that code can be more concise, expressive, and possible easier to read and maintain.

Historically CoffeeScript came first and offered this mode of writing code for many years. ES6 is a recent development. ES6 is officially slated as the next version of Javascript and will officially be supported by browsers directly eventually. ES6 has a few more things than CoffeeScript, mostly because it's newer and its ambitions are grander.

Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't undestand: when ES6 comes to all of browsers by default. It would mean that now JS has new cool features. So will CS be updated to implements this features somehow or it won't? Is it right to ask such questions?

Comment: It already is being updated; see the fork implementation linked in my footnote.

Comment: @Vad Who knows?! Go ask the developers of CS for their roadmap. We cannot tell you. They're not obliged to. Maybe CS will wither and go away and be de facto replaced by ES6+.